# Linking errors GoogleMock with my C++project under linux

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, googletest

I want to use GMock in my project. First of all I compiled GMock and GTest. The sequence of my actions (I use Linux):

1. git clone googlemock and googletest
2. go to GIT/googletest/googlemock/build-aux/ directory run cmake ..
   and then make
3. As the result I got: libgmock.a and libgmock_main.a

`My project` has the structure: **build**, **inc**, **src** and **lib** directories. In *build* directory I run cmake .. and make. In *inc* dir I placed all headers from GIT/googletest/googlemock/include/ and GIT/googletest/googletest/include/. In *lib* dir lays libgmock.a only. In *src* - sources of my project.

My `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
project(blockchain)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
file(GLOB CPPS "*.cpp")

include_directories("../inc/")
link_directories("../lib/")

add_definitions(-Wall -O2 -std=c++11)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPPS})
target_link_libraries(blockchain gmock)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

When I try to make my project (typing `cmake .. && make` in build dir) I get linking errors:

> CMakeFiles/blockchain.dir/main.cpp.o: In function main':
>   main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference
>   totesting::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
>       main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b): undefined reference to testing::UnitTest::Run()' ../lib/libgmock.a(gmock-all.cc.o): In
>   functiontesting::internal::scoped_ptr
>
> > ::reset(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream) [clone .part.81] [clone .constprop.367]':
> >         gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)' ../lib/libgmock.a(gmock-all.cc.o): In
> >     functiontesting::internal::MutexBase::AssertHeld() const [clone
> >     .constprop.368]':
> >         gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)' gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x2b2): undefined
> >     reference
> >     totesting::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity,
> >     char const, int)'
> >         gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x2fd): undefined reference to testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()' gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x312):
> >     undefined reference totesting::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
> >         ../lib/libgmock.a(gmock-all.cc.o): In function testing::internal::Expect(bool, char const*, int,
> >     std::__cxx11::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&) [clone .part.51]':
> >     gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x910): undefined reference
> >     totesting::Message::Message()'
> >         gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x926): undefined reference to testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type,
> >     char const*, int, char const*)' gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x931): undefined
> >     reference
> >     totesting::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&)
> >     const'
> >         gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x939): undefined reference to testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
> >     gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x94b): undefined reference
> >     totesting::internal::IsTrue(bool)'

And a lot of others linking errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you move the headers and compiled libs from gtest/gmock directories to some directories in your project? According to [gtest docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) "robust and flexible approach is to build gtest as part of that project directly".

Answer (score 1):

`gmock` depends on `gtest`. You added the former, but not the latter.

Comment: This is not a problem. You can link with only `gmock` target and it will work. On one machine I have even once encountered a problem with double free in `libc` because of linking both to `gmock` and `gtest`. I don't remember what exactly caused the crash on tests shutdown, but it had something to do with static data initialization.